# Shiny can not display different "webGLOutput" on different tab panels?

Tags: r, plot, tabs, shiny, rgl

I am trying to displaying different 3D plots in different tab panels, but I found that 3D plot only displayed in the first tab panel. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927741/shinys-tabsetpanel-not-displaying-plots-in-multiple-tabs), `plotOutput`s parameter `outputId` should be unique, and in my case IDs are unique over the entail shiny app. Some lines of my app are as follow:

```
ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(    
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("VWC", webGLOutput("VWC3DPlot")), 
      tabPanel("TEMP", webGLOutput("TEMP3DPlot"))
    )
  )
))


server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    # set dir；
    dataDir <- "C:/Users/PH/Desktop/data/DATA/"

    # store dataframe of attribute to list；
    dfList <- readIntoDF(dataDir) # readIntoDF() is function that return a list

    # extract dataframe from list
    dfVWC <- dfList$VWC
    dfTEMP <- dfList$TEMP

    # processing of dataframes
    dfVWC <- transformDF(dfVWC)
    dfTEMP <- transformDF(dfTEMP)    

    # prepare grid for kriging；
    grd <- expand.grid(x=seq(from=0, to=600, by=200),
                       y=seq(from=0, to=500, by=200))

    # Kriging；
    dfVWCkrige <- krigingFun(dfVWC, grd)
    dfTEMPKrige <- krigingFun(dfTEMP, grd)

    krigeList <- list("VWCKrige" = dfVWCkrige, "TEMPKrige" = dfTEMPKrige)

    return(krigeList)
  })  # end of dataInput


  ### create cubs；
   output$VWC3DPlot <- renderWebGL({
     createCubes(dataInput()$VWCKrige) # createCubes() is a function that use output of kriging and shinyrgl pkg to create cubes;
   })

  output$TEMP3DPlot <- renderWebGL({
    createCubes(dataInput()$TEMPKrige)
  })

})
```

Since there are hundreds of lines, I could not to post all of them.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670908/r-shiny-multiple-tabpanel-in-tabsetpanel-not-loading), I updated the version of `shiny`, but had no effect on my case.

Comment: I wonder if it is an issue with webGL graphs. Does it work if you change it to normal R plots?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  You are right, when I changed it to `plotOutput`, it worked. So how to handle this issue?

Comment: You should make sure you see the same behaviour in the latest versions of rgl and rglwidget from R-forge; if so, put together a bug report.  It needs to be self-contained, nobody else can run the code in your question.

Comment: @user2554330 I have updated package `rgl`, `shiny` and `rglwidget`, but I still got the same problem.

Comment: So simplify your example, and post a bug report in the appropriate place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be using `shinyRGL`.  Don't use it, `rgl` has what you need.  Here's an example that works for me:

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("red",
      rglwidgetOutput('thewidget1')),
    tabPanel("green",
      rglwidgetOutput('thewidget2'))
  ))
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(rgl)

options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  x <- rnorm(100)
  y <- 2*rnorm(100)
  z <- 10*rnorm(100)
  open3d()
  plot3d(x, y, z, col = "red")
  scene1 <- scene3d()
  plot3d(z, y, x, col = "green")
  scene2 <- scene3d()
  rgl.close()

  save <- options(rgl.inShiny = TRUE)
  on.exit(options(save))

  output$thewidget1 <- renderRglwidget(
    rglwidget(scene1)
  )

  output$thewidget2 <- renderRglwidget(
    rglwidget(scene2)
  )

})
```

By the way, we would have got here a lot sooner if you had posted a reproducible example as requested.